# How to make cross-frame-scripting work locally

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, dom

I want to load a page on the intranet and login automatically but this error happens in Firefox 4 due to the cross-frame-scripting-policy:

> Permission denied to access property 'LoginForm'

How can I work around that or are there alternative ways to achieve that?

**Don't lecture me on the security problems this may cause!**
I know the risk myself, but since this computer doesn't have any access to the internet it doesn't matter.

Here's how I tried to make it work:

```
<frameset cols="500,*">
    <frame src="script.html" name='leftFrame'>
    <frame src='http://intranet/login/' name='login'>
</frameset>
```

script.html looks like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Login" 
        onClick="parent.login.LoginForm.password.value='MYPASSWORD'">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to **place the file** in that server and run it ...

No matter what will you try, you will end up getting such error as that's a javascript violation, not machine/browser setting.

Changing things locally and update to server upon Save, and test some more

With [Expresso](https://espressoapp.com/), [Coda](https://www.panic.com/coda/), etc it's easy to do that, they will upload the file to FTP on each Save File iteration.

Comment: I can't deploy to that server because it's my corporate's one.

Comment: then you can't do anything! I tried that myself to fill up the login form automatically and login ... The only way is to have a file in that server, that will do as you told.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this. I'll leave the question open for another day. Maybe someone comes up with a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to run privileged code for the login bit.  That is, instead of a `file://` web page, use an extension.